# NSWindow mouse events

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouseevent, nswindow

How can I get mouse events for NSWindow? I want to know when a use hovers over a window and clicks a window. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following methods:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

}

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

}
```